# To make single salesforce connection for multiple salesforce operation in wso2 EI

Tags: java, salesforce, connector, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am performing multiple salesforce operations in wso2 EI service. For each operation I made `salesforce.init` which works fine, but I want to maintain a single salesforce connection which is reusable for multiple operations wherever I want.

Can anyone please suggest to me how to perform this task?

I have the following docs for reference:

1) https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Salesforce+Operations

2) https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Queries

````
<sequence name="FeedsProcess_Query-Sequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="LoggerText" value="=====Fetch Query Process Sequence======"/>
    </log>
    <!-- =============Fetch Vehicle ID======================= -->
    <property description="SingleQuote" name="SingleQuote" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'"/>
    <property description="QueryToFetchVehicleData" expression="fn:concat(get-property('Sales_FetchVehicleQuery'),' WHERE Name =',get-property('SingleQuote'),get-property('VIN__c'),get-property('SingleQuote'))" name="VehicleQuery" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:VehicleQuery" name="VehicleQuery"/>
    </log>
    <!-- =======================SalesForce Process======================= -->
    <sequence description="Load_SFConfig_CarSalestoSF" key="QRSag_ASGSalesforceInitializer_dev6"/>
    <!-- <sequence description="Load_SFConfig_CarSalestoSF" key="QRSag_ASGSalesforceInitializer_devMerge"/> -->
    <salesforcerest.init>
        <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
        <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
        <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
        <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
        <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
        <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
        <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
        <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
        <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
    </salesforcerest.init>
    <salesforcerest.query>
        <queryString>{$ctx:VehicleQuery}</queryString>
    </salesforcerest.query>
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="VehicleQueryDetails" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="//records/Id/text()" name="VehicleQueryId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('VehicleQueryDetails')" name="====VehicleQueryResponse==="/>
    </log>
    <!-- =============Fetch VehicleOwnership Contact Name======================= -->
    <property description="QueryToFetchVOData" expression="fn:concat(get-property('Sales_FetchVOQuery'),' WHERE VIN__c =',get-property('SingleQuote'),get-property('VehicleQueryId'),get-property('SingleQuote'),' AND ERA_customer_ID__c=',get-property('SingleQuote'),get-property('FormattedCustomerId'),get-property('SingleQuote'))" name="VOQuery" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('VOQuery')" name="====VOQueryQuery==="/>
    </log>
    <sequence description="Load_SFConfig_CarSalestoSF" key="QRSag_ASGSalesforceInitializer_dev6"/>
    <!-- <sequence description="Load_SFConfig_CarSalestoSF" key="QRSag_ASGSalesforceInitializer_devMerge"/> -->
    <salesforcerest.init>
        <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
        <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
        <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
        <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
        <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
        <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
        <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
        <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
        <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
    </salesforcerest.init>
    <salesforcerest.query>
        <queryString>{$ctx:VOQuery}</queryString>
    </salesforcerest.query>
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="VOQueryDetails" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('VOQueryDetails')" name="====VOQueryResponse==="/>
    </log>
    <property expression="//records/ContactName__c/text()" name="VOContactName__c" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</sequence>```


Best way to perform multiple salesforce operation by making single connection.
````

Comment: We handle the token refreshing part in the init. Therefore it is better if we have the init before each of the salesforce connector operation. Even if we use the init multiple times, we don't do the token generation each time. That is, if the token is expired only we refresh it.

Comment: If you want to improve the code readability, you can save the init config in the local entry and use it while calling the connector operation as follows.

``
<localEntry key="SalesforceConfig" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <salesforcerest.init>
        <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
        <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
        .
        .
        .
    </salesforcerest.init>
</localEntry>

 <salesforcerest.query configKey="SalesforceConfig">
        <queryString>{$ctx:VOQuery}</queryString>
 </salesforcerest.query>
``

Comment: Hi @ShakilaSasikaran
Thanks for your answer. Works fine in Sandbox environment. But In production perspective, is there any issue will arise if we use multiple salesforce.init for each query operation?kindly let me know. Thanks once again.